# Django: a modelChoiceField depend on another modelChoiceField

Tags: ajax, django, modelchoicefield

i have two ModelChoiceFields that are populated with database :

```
t1=MyModelChoiceField1(queryset=operation_Bancaire.objects.all(),to_field_name='type_tiers',required=False)
t2=MyModelChoiceField2(queryset=operation_Bancaire.objects.all(),required=False)
```

i need to let the `t2` depends on `t1` . 
for example : 
if i choose value1 in `t1` , `t2` shows only values filtred by the value1 chooses in the first ModelChoiceField `t1`

i searched a lot about  this and found some information that `Ajax` would help me  to do so. but i'm not sure if it will let me control my ModelChoiceFields as i want specially that my ChoiceFields are populated from database, Because i have never worked with `Ajax`.
Any Help please so i can be right oriented to achieve what i need.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, ajax/javascript is the best way to do this. There is no inbuilt way in django to do this dynamically. [This](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) link is by far the most comprehensive in explaining how to implement ajax in django.

Comment: Thank You So much for your answer. I guess the link you gived me is what i need. i will accept your answer for sure. :)